# Error in Dojo 1.8 upgrade Error:{"message":"'registry' is undefined"}

Tags: dojo

I want to set the data in bodydiv how it possible.

**Error** in `Dojo 1.8 upgrade Error:{"message":"'registry' is undefined"}`

```
function setBodyData(link) {

        if(!stringExists(link)) {

            return;
        }


        dojo.xhrGet ({
            url: link
            ,timeout: 50000
            ,content: {session_id:session_logout}
            ,handleAs:'text'

            ,load:function(data){
                alert("data:"+dumpObj(data));
                var l_object = dojo.byId('bodyDiv');

                //dijit.byId('bodyDiv').innerHTML = data;

                registry.byId('bodyDiv').set('content',data);

            }
```

Comment: Remember you should require `dijit/registry` in order to call it. If you do it, but registry still undefined, check console for 404 error. Also `dijit.byId('bodyDiv').set('content',data)` will probably work

Comment: this error is come using dijit.byID
Error:{"message":"'dijit.byId(...)' is null or not an object","number":-2146823281,"description":"'dijit.byId(...)' is null or not an object"}

Comment: Did you set async:false in dojoConfig?

Comment: `dijit.byId()` is deprecated in 1.8.  You should use `registry.byid()` instead.  @Tommi is correct in recommending your require `dijit/registry`.  It's hard to tell what your real problem is without posting more code.

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly you now get the error? "'dijit.byId(...)' is null or not an object"?

Make sure the div 'bodyDiv' exists and try:

```
dom.byId("bodyDiv").innerHTML = data;
```

Of cause you must also require "dojo/dom".